# Decimal assert two decimal places even if zero

Tags: c#, decimal

I have a problem I have not found any solution to:

I am getting data from a SAP system, which I receive as decimal. Sometimes I get values with one decimal place, ex. -18083195.1

My 3rd party front-end table framework needs it to be -18083195.10, because sometimes users want to copy the value between cells and the framework converts -18083195.1 to -180831951 in the copy event.

Without converting between decimal and string, I need to assert that the values always are in the the 0.00 decimal format, and of decimal type.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: the two decimal places is only relevant when displaying the value to the user (i.e string) you can round the values before storing the decimal but that is modifying the actual value..

Comment: Try this: `Decimal sample = -18083195.1M + 0.00M;` (note adding `0.00M`); in general case: `Decimal result = source + 0.00M;`

Comment: So the 3rd party component don't implement a Format property or CellFormatting event?

Comment: @dmitry adding 0.0 to a floating point variable does not change its value at all

Comment: @PatrickHofman: citation required :-)

Comment: See the post of Dmitry above.

Answer (score 0):

You can check that the value is a decimal type using `sample.GetType() == typeof(decimal)`.

Comment: @Henk, The OP wants to know how to check the type, and no-one else had answered this, so I thought I'd give my answer.  But I don't know what they want to do if it isn't a decimal, so I can't say what they would do next.

Comment: He wants to _assert_ they are of type decimal. Not find out.

Comment: @Henk, OK, I have probably misunderstood what Fredrik wanted; but it looks like he's sorted his problem anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your suggestions!

I found the error, and it was in my table-framework (Handsontable), where, of course, the values are converted to string and back. Due to the varying demands of the client, they wanted a specific format for percentage values, another for regular values, which confused the framework number format functionality. I found a way to work around that!

Thanks!
Fredrik